# How to iterate a java array

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm setting up a role based authorization in spring boot using user role as either client or supplier in thymeleaf drop down selection. The list items are coming from a java `private List<String> userRoles()`. How do I iterate the list items in the view?

I have tried using a Role.java model class and User.java model. I have the     List items within `List<String> userRoles()` as

```
List<String> ROLE = new ArrayList<>();
ROLE.add("CLIENT");
ROLE.add("SUPPLIER");
```

**Controller Java List Items**

```
private List<String> userRoles() {
    List<String> ROLE = new ArrayList<>();
    ROLE.add("CLIENT");
    ROLE.add("SUPPLIER");
    return ROLE;
}
```

**View Iteration**

```
<select th:field="*{userRole}">
    <option th:each="*ROLE:${userRoles}" th:value="${ROLE}" th:text="${ROLE}">
        Select Role
    </option>
</select>
```

I expect the ROLE variable to have elements CLIENT and SUPPLIER, but this is what i get 
`'!', '!=', '%', '&#', '&&', '&gt;', '&lt;', '*', '+', '+=', ',', '-', '.', '/', <, <=, <Literal>, '==', '>', '>=', IDENTIFIER, STRING_IDENTIFIER, and, div, empty, eq, ge, gt, le, lt, mod, ne, not, or, '|' or '||' expected, got ':'`
I wonder whether the logic is wrong or completely not the way it is done

Comment: the `userRoles()` is a method. Is an instance of the class encapsulating the method available as requestAttribute or is the list returned by the `userRoles()` method available as a requestAttribute when the thymeleaf code is running?

Comment: This line `<select th:field="*{userRole}">` it should be replaced with `<select th:field="*{ROLE}">`. More details in [7.5 Dropdown/List selectors](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors) section from Thymeleaf documentation

Comment: Just a suggestion. Better if you can use camel notation when declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error message is because you have an extra asterisk in your `th:each` expression:

```
th:each="*ROLE:${userRoles}"
```

should probably be

```
th:each="ROLE: ${userRoles}"
```